# Где взять apache 2.2

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Необходимо на VPS поднять для разработки дубликат существующего сайта на Moguta.

На хостинге установлена ubuntu 16.04

Moguta требует php5.3, apache 2.2

Пробовал поднять LAMP, но, на сайте конечно же, php ругается. Пытался найти apache2.2 - на репозиториях вижу только 2.4 или я не так смотрю.

Прочитал, что можно добавить другие репозитории, но где их взять? как узнать есть ли на репозитории apache2.2?

В идеале конечно же было бы установить lamp-server, где комплект mySql5 + apache2.2 + php5.3

Comment: значительно проще будет взять другую cms.

Comment: Поддерживаю @aleksandrbarakin. Плюс ко всему, если выставить старые версии в интернет - велика вероятность, что из твоего сайта сделают ботнет, потому что уязвимости никто не закрывал.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin речь о доработке существующего сайта. Перенос с одной cms на другую равносилен разработке нового